# Make multiple shapes work together in Zelle Graphics

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I'm a beginner in Python and I'm using the Zelle's Graphics library.  I wish to draw multiple shapes and make them behave as one.  For example, I might call a group of shapes 'x' and when I use the builtin `move()` method the entire collection of shapes move.

Comment: You can use turtle polies.

Comment: If you provide a code snippet of what you have so-far, someone may provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I envision is a new `GraphicsObject` that is actually a group of graphics objects.  Below is a skeletal example with just enough code to demonstrate the idea:

```
from graphics import *

class GraphicsGroup(GraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(options=[])

        self.components = []

    def draw(self, graphwin):
        for component in self.components:
            component.draw(graphwin)

        return self

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        for component in self.components:
            component.move(dx, dy)

    def add_component(self, component):
        if isinstance(component, GraphicsObject):
            self.components.append(component)

win = GraphWin("Group Test", 200, 200)

# Some example objects borrowed from graphics.py source docstrings
text = Text(Point(35, 35), "Centered Text")
polygon = Polygon(Point(10, 10), Point(50, 30), Point(20, 70))
circle = Circle(Point(50, 50), 10)
rectangle = Rectangle(Point(25, 60), Point(60, 25))

group = GraphicsGroup()
group.add_component(text)
group.add_component(polygon)
group.add_component(circle)
group.add_component(rectangle)

group.draw(win)

win.getMouse()  # Pause to view result

group.move(100, 100)

win.getMouse()  # Pause to view result
win.close()
```

Since `GraphicsGroup` isn't really a graphic object itself, we override `draw` and `move` instead of `_draw` and `_move` like a proper graphics entity.

Comment: @AnnZen, before you throw my comment back at me, the wild card import `from graphics import *` is the idiom for Zelle Graphics and one of the rare exceptions to "don't use wild card imports" other than for short code examples.

Comment: Funny, I never received this comment in my inbox.

Comment: @AnnZen, I left it as a comment on one of your questions.  ;-)

Comment: When I said *this comment*, I meant the one that begins with *"@AnnZen, before you throw my comment..."*